# Advanced sorting in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table with a column containing productnames.

I want to sort it by productname ascending, BUT i want the productnames containing the word "accessory" to be sorted LAST.

How can this be done?

Comment: `ORDER BY` accepts a comma-separated list of expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common way to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY product_name LIKE '%accessory%', product_name
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
ORDER BY LOCATE('accessory', product_name), product_name
```

The clause `product_name LIKE '%accessory%'` is a Boolean expression, which returns `0` or `1`, so all the rows that don't match will return `0` and will appear earlier in the sort order.

`LOCATE('accessory', product_name)` works similarly, but will return `0` for no match or the integer location of the first match. In this case, there's little difference between the two.

Comment: Shouldn't you order by `LOCATE('accessory', name)` first?

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT *, 
(CASE WHEN `productname` LIKE '%accessory%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `relevance`
     FROM `tablename` ORDER BY `relevance`, `productname` ASC
```

You can give relevance based on conditions in mysql using [case.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

Obviously you can add your WHERE clause in there just before the ORDER BY statement, but for this example I just select everything